# Create JSON for place name and coordinates

Tags: json

I have the following:

pt-PT:[Lisboa,Portugal][38.7138,9.1394];

en-GB:[London,UK][51.5072,0.1275]

So, for each culture, e.g. pt-PT and en-GB code, I would like to define one place with its coordenates.

What is the correct JSON format for this?

Answer (score 0):

The interest of a JSON is that you can set your data as you want.
A good idea in your case is to follow the GeoJSON format.

http://geojson.org/

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [38.7138,9.1394]},
            "properties": {"city": "Lisboa", "country": "Portugal"}
        }
    ]
}
```